# XAMPP doesn't work after update to macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, xampp, macos-big-sur

Today I updated my mac to macOS Big Sur and I can't open XAMPP. When I click on app it doesn't give any response.

Do you know how solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem by updating xampp ver 7.2.34 .

https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: make sure you backup up `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/` don't want to lose you httpd-vhosts.conf

Answer (score 8):

You can do a clean installation, but you will lose all your old files and databases. I suggest making a backup of this data.

Uninstall old versions of xampp.

## Installation of Xampp by the brew

```
brew install --cask xampp
```

## If you don't have the brew installed

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

[HomeBrew](https://brew.sh/index)

Comment: I tried this today and got this fatal error from the script: "xampp-osx-8.2.0-0-installer” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

Answer (score 6):

After Big Sur installation if XAMPP is not opening, get newest version of XAMPP (7.4.12) from their web site.

If you end up with error "Error starting “XAMPP” stack: cannot calculate MAC address: signal killed". After installing the latest version, do following:

Go to terminal ->
cd ~/.bitnami/stackman/helpers
Mv hyperkit hyperkit_backup

After that XAMPP opens and tells its the first time opening, but at least I found all the files etc as before Big Sur upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

Install XAMPP 7.4.12, works perfectly in MacOS Big Sur

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had Xampp 7.4.9 and update Mac OS to Big Sur. Xampp didn't want to launch after that. I lost access to all my projects inside of /htdocs folder hidden somewhere in path structure of my virtual machine.
Kindly note I used version 7.4.9-VM (not 7.4.9-Installer) that is why all my files blocked inside of
*/Users/'your_user_name'/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/vm/machine.qcow2*
Actually all files are important here:
*/Users/'your_user_name'/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp*
not only machine.qcow2

My solution is kind a mix of before mentioned solutions because they didn’t help in full.

1. First of all make a backup - copy old structure (with blocked files) to some directory - all this structure:
   */Users/'your_user_name'/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp*
   (To see hidden files in MacOS use [Command]+[Shift]+[.])
   You also can just rename
   */Users/'your_user_name'/.bitnami/*
   to something like
   */Users/'your_user_name'/.my_blocked_files_bitnami/*
2. As programmers here advised to install 7.4.12-VM I installed this version. Very important to install "Virtual Machine" version (as you can see there are 2 installers for each version of Xampp)
3. Right after I launched 7.4.12-VM the new directory was created here:
   */Users/'your_user_name'/.bitnami/*
   and Xampp will work properly but with no your old projects.
4. Do not do this step: As programmers here advised to change only one file
   */Users/'your_user_name'/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/vm/machine.qcow2*
   for me it was not enough - Xampp failed with an error:
   ERROR: Error starting "XAMPP" stack: cannot start stack: ssh not accessible
5. My solution was put whole structure from folder xampp
   */Users/'your_user_name'/.my_blocked_files_bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp*
   to here:
   */Users/'your_user_name'/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp*

You may before rename your current folder
*/Users/'your_user_name'/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp*
to something like
*/Users/'your_user_name'/.bitnami/stackman/machines/new_xampp_without_my_projects*

6. Then launch Xampp (Xampp should say something about incopatible versions but allows to continue), start all services, mount the disk. press "Expore" and you should see all your old projects.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me but the version 7.4.12 seems to be working. I download it from the link I'll but below. I've been reading and the problem seems to be that Big Sur changes some paths that are set by default and so the apps won't launch. Same thing happened to Apache NetBeans.

**XAMPP Download Link:**

(https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Mac%20OS%20X/7.4.12/)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. This is how I solved it:
First, be sure that you back up your files in XAMPP VM. Your files are in

> /Users/'*your_user_name*'/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/vm/machine.qcow2

Then you can reinstall XAMPP again. I have installed 7.4.12 and it worked fine.
If you see stack error message, this is what you have to do:

1. Close XAMPP
2. Open a terminal and remove the stack folder with the following code:

   rm -rf ~/.bitnami/stackman
3. Open XAMPP and check if a new stackman folder is created.

> /Users/'*your_user_name*'/.bitnami/stackman/

4. If it does not, then start XAPP and stop again. When the stackman folder is created, override the file below with your backup file.

> /Users/'*your_user_name*'/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/vm/machine.qcow2

5. Close XAMPP again and restart again.

Voila! Here are your files...

Comment: Thanks work fine. But VM change my old ip with new one. Can we change it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried reinstalling XAMPP on MACos Big Sur, and it worked. However, my files are not recovered.

Answer (score 1):

you can type this code in terminal

before this code you should close xampp

```
rm -rf ~/.bitnami/stackman
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting error message saying:

> Cannot calculate MAC Address: Using fd 10 for I/O notifications hv_vm_create HV_ERROR (unspecified error)

you need to download new hyperkit from bitnami and replace the current one

```
cd /tmp

curl -LJO "https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/hyperkit/hyperkit-testing-`20210430"`

mv /tmp/hyperkit-testing-20210430 ~/.bitnami/stackman/helpers/hyperkit

chmod +x ~/.bitnami/stackman/helpers/hyperkit
```

read tutorial here:
https://floyk.com/en/post/xampp-doesnt-work-after-update-to-macos-big-sur